# Beautiful soup parse multiple tags with different Attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

`sentences.find_all(['p','h2'],attrs={['class':None,'class':Not None]})`.

This is an invalid syntax but is there any alternative to doing this. I want p tags with one attribute  and h2 tag with another attribute and I need them sequentially not like finding them as two parse tree i.e I don't want to do

1. `sentences.find_all('p',attrs={'class':None])`
2. `sentences.find_all('h2',attrs={'class':Not None])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS selector with `,` ([CSS reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_comma.asp)):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<p class="cls1">Select this</p>
<p class="cls2">Don't select this</p>
<h2 class="cls3">Select this</h2>
<h2 class="cls4">Don't select this</h2>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select("p.cls1, h2.cls3"):
    print(tag)
```

Prints:

```html
<p class="cls1">Select this</p>
<h2 class="cls3">Select this</h2>
```

---

EDIT: To select multiple tags and one tag has to have empty attributes:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<p>Select this</p>
<p class="cls2">Don't select this</p>
<h2 class="cls3">Select this</h2>
<h2 class="cls4">Don't select this</h2>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select("p, h2.cls3"):
    if tag.name == "p" and len(tag.attrs) != 0:
        continue
    print(tag)
```

Prints:

```html
<p>Select this</p>
<h2 class="cls3">Select this</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works .I was wondering if it is possible  to extract all p tags with no attributes in this case. If i just go with p then it would fetch all tags with / without attributes. and something P.None seems invalid in this case

Comment: @Innovative_roh You can check length of `.attrs` atribute. If there's any, reject it. See my edit.